# How can I create a bash script which runs irb, then some ruby code?

Tags: bash, ruby, test

I'm trying to do this to make unit testing a breeze for myself.

The contents of an example script in question are as follows:

```
irb
require 'random_utils.rb'
a = SuccessChecker.new
```

Right now this just opens irb.  I'd like to be able to run arbitrary code afterward, so that I might make scripts to make my life easier by requiring files, instantiating classes, populating test conditions, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing commands sequentially, so the shell executes `irb`, waits until `irb` get closed and executes the next command (in your case `require 'random_utils.rb'`)…

What you want is to provide the script to `irb` via `STDIN`

```
irb <<EOF
require 'random_utils.rb'
a = SuccessChecker.new
EOF
```

But this will probably not do what you want as `irb` is for interactive use, you should consider using your normal ruby interpreter instead, e.g:

```
ruby <<EOF
require 'random_utils.rb'
a = SuccessChecker.new
EOF
```

Comment: I have been using irb to load these files manually and poke at the code to test it interactively, so I think that's what I want to do, though I might change my mind :)

Thank you for this.  I thought it would be some simple character or something.

Comment: @ac7v see http://i.imgur.com/t6gNQ.png for details, e.g. irb will show return values and echos the commands, that is probably not what you want - there is no real benefit from using irb to run non interactive things.

Comment: I suppose I'll just write the testing code in a separate .rb file (for cleanliness).  I guess that's the better way of doing it anyway. I consider this an answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're ready to take the next step and use a unit testing library.

[Here's an introduction](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/07/28/how-do-i-test-my-code-with-minitest/) to [minitest](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest.html), built into Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Bookmarked.  Don't have enough rep to +1 you yet so I'm saying thank you instead!

Comment: Cool, hope you enjoy it :)

Answer (score 0):

A modern solution to this is to use the `pry` gem and make this a plain old ruby script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pry'
require 'random_utils.rb'
a = SuccessChecker.new
binding.pry
```

will dump you into a debugger wherever binding.pry is...