# How can I launch irb from a bash script, execute some commands, then pass the irb session to the console?

Tags: bash, ruby

I am creating a ruby gem and to speed my testing I wrote a script to build and install my gem, then to open irb for me to manually poke around.

How can I run the following ruby commands before passing the irb session to the console:

`require 'my_gem'`

`MyGem.method_to_test`

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

gem build my_gem.gemspec
gem install my_gem-0.0.1.gem
irb
```

this is similar to the following question, except I need to know how to pass the session back to the console:

[How can I create a bash script which runs irb, then some ruby code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45099/how-can-i-create-a-bash-script-which-runs-irb-then-some-ruby-code)

Comment: I think that in the middle of the script, you could change by typing '#!rubypath' while replacing rubypath to the path to the ruby executable file.

Answer (score 2):

An excerpt of `irb`'s manpage on Debian "Jessie" 8:

```
-r library     Same as `ruby -r'.  Causes irb to load the library using require.
```

For your example, just use the following command:

```
irb -r my_gem
```